How do you optimize inference batch size in c++ pytorch libtorch?
I have an inference service using cpu (will migrate to gpu later but right now I am stuck with cpu) that is taking request through thrift and returning inference result
Right now its doing inference 1 request at a time, I think libtorch internally have some cpu optimization like SIMD that can make batch inference more optimal
here a simple c++ code I test with a toy model (model that emulate euclidean distance) with benchmark of each batch number
    #include <torch/script.h> // One-stop header.
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <vector>
    #include <ATen/Parallel.h> // Required for get_num_threads and set_num_threads
    #include <random> 
    std::vector<float> batch_infer_distance(torch::jit::Module& model, const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& point_pairs) {
        int batch_size = point_pairs.size();
        torch::Tensor input_tensor = torch::empty({batch_size, 4});
        for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; ++i) {
            input_tensor[i] = torch::tensor(point_pairs[i]);
        }
        
        torch::Tensor output = model.forward({input_tensor}).toTensor();
        std::vector<float> distances(output.data_ptr<float>(), output.data_ptr<float>() + output.numel());
        return distances;
    }


    std::vector<std::vector<float>> generate_random_points(int batch_size) {
        std::vector<std::vector<float>> point_pairs;
        point_pairs.reserve(batch_size);
        std::random_device rd;  
        std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0.0, 100.0); // Uniform distribution between 0 and 100
        for (int i = 0; i < batch_size; ++i) {
            float x1 = dis(gen);
            float y1 = dis(gen);
            float x2 = dis(gen);
            float y2 = dis(gen);
            point_pairs.push_back({x1, y1, x2, y2});
        }

        return point_pairs;
    }

    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

        int num_threads = at::get_num_threads();
        
        // Print the number of threads
        std::cout << "Current number of threads: " << num_threads << std::endl;

        torch::jit::Module model;
        try {
            model = torch::jit::load("distance_model_traced.pt");
        } catch (const c10::Error& e) {
            std::cerr << "Error loading the model\n";
            return -1;
        }
        
        std::vector<int> batch_sizes = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}; // Example batch sizes to test
        
        for (int batch_size : batch_sizes) {
            double total_time = 0.0;
            int trial_num = 100000;

            for (int trial = 0; trial < trial_num; ++trial) {
                // Generate random input points for this batch size
                std::vector<std::vector<float>> point_pairs = generate_random_points(batch_size);
                
                // Start timing
                auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                
                // Perform inference
                batch_infer_distance(model, point_pairs);
                
                // End timing
                auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
                
                // Accumulate the time for this trial
                total_time += duration.count();
            }
            double average_time = total_time / trial_num;
            
            // Print the average time for the batch size
            std::cout << "Batch Size: " << batch_size << ", Average Time: " << average_time << " seconds" << std::endl;
        }


        return 0;
    }

Current number of threads: 4
Model loaded successfully.
Batch Size: 1, Average Time: 1.86423e-05 seconds, Throughput: 53641.4 samples/second
Batch Size: 2, Average Time: 1.90694e-05 seconds, Throughput: 104880 samples/second
Batch Size: 4, Average Time: 2.47976e-05 seconds, Throughput: 161306 samples/second
Batch Size: 8, Average Time: 3.45569e-05 seconds, Throughput: 231502 samples/second
Batch Size: 16, Average Time: 6.15277e-05 seconds, Throughput: 260046 samples/second
Batch Size: 32, Average Time: 9.73409e-05 seconds, Throughput: 328742 samples/second
Batch Size: 64, Average Time: 0.000174497 seconds, Throughput: 366770 samples/second
Batch Size: 128, Average Time: 0.000330429 seconds, Throughput: 387375 samples/second
Batch Size: 256, Average Time: 0.000638286 seconds, Throughput: 401074 samples/second
Batch Size: 512, Average Time: 0.00125685 seconds, Throughput: 407367 samples/second
Batch Size: 1024, Average Time: 0.00267883 seconds, Throughput: 382256 samples/second

My ultimate goal is to decrease the size of aws server or the number of aws server I am using.
My question is

It would seem like in this model given the current feature size , batch size of 512 is the most optimal (since 1ms is acceptable for our api service), am i measuring performance correctly?
What controls throughput in this case? What exactly is making bigger batch obtaining higher throughput and why is batch of 1024 have lower throughput than 512
My guess is that it has to do with the size of the model + size of feature + batch size fitting into l1 cache , and simd , is there other factor?
Is there anything I am missing with performance tuning , I am benchmarking inference only right now, how would I bench mark thrift + inference, I would probably allocate X thread for thrift and Y thread for inference but how do I find the optimal number?

